# THREE.js: How to calculate how many screen pixels represent 1 world coordinate unit

Tags: three.js, coordinate-systems

In `THREE.js`:
How to calculate how many screen pixels represent one world coordinate unit?

For example:

```
var v = new Vector(1, 0, 0)
```

I want to know how many screen pixels do represent one world coordinate unit.

Comment: Depends on the type of a camera and on the distance from that vector to the camera.

Comment: @prisoner849 camera is PerspectiveCamera

Answer (score 0):

The term you are looking for is [`Rasterisation`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasterisation).

It describes the transformation process between a k-dimensional vector space and a (mostly) two-dimensional display-space("raster" image) displayed on a *Viewing Device* like a monitor.

> I want to know how many screen pixels do represent one world coordinate unit.

This depends on all the aspects mentioned in the article.